# Call a function in another file using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have file x1.py, In that class vpn(),I have check_vpn() and connect_vpn() functions.I have tried to call this 2 function in another file x2.py but get module has no attribute error.

```
import x1

from x1 import check_vpn

from x1 import connect_vpn


class vpn():
vpn_bin= '/home/'   
flag= False

def check_vpn(self):    
    myCmd = os.popen('ps aux | grep vpnc').read()
    print(myCmd)

    for data in myCmd:
        if re.search(r'vpn.conf\b',myCmd): 
            print("Vpn connected")
            self.flag = True
            return self.flag  
            break

def connect_vpn(self,token1):  

    print("#########")
```

## Main program starts here:

```
obj=vpn()

obj.check_vpn()

if(obj.flag == False):
    print("###################   VpN is not connected   ########")
with open('auth1.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    token = data["vpn_detail"]["tokens"]
    for i in range(len(token)):
        token1 = token[i]
        #print(token[i])
        print(token1)
        i = i+1   
        obj.connect_vpn(token1)'
```

I  want  output  of  check_vpn() and connect_vpn() in x2.py, but I got this

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./x2.py", line 4, in

```
f1.check_vpn
```

AttributeError: module 'x1' has no attribute 'check_vpn'

Comment: You need to make a [mcve], including the full error message and working code.

Comment: When you do `import x1`, you *are* doing it in `x2.py`, right?

Comment: yes@GreenCloakGuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues here with your code

- You have not tabbed out the code inside your vpn class, in python things under methods or classes must be tabbed.
- your for loop in check_vpn gets each "data" in "myCmd" but when you search you search in "myCmd", not the individual piece of "data"
- You didn't include import re and os statements the x1.py that you provided, but I assume they are there in your code
- You have a break statement after a return statement -> so it will never be reached (not a major flaw but I thought I'd mention it
- you seem to be importing x1 into x1 but you should be importing into x2
- You also want to import your class as a whole, you don't need to import methods that are in your class

I made some changes to fix the above errors but there may be more that I didn't catch

x1

```
import os
import re

class vpn():
    vpn_bin= '/home/'   
    flag= False

    def check_vpn(self):    
        myCmd = os.popen('ps aux | grep vpnc').read()
        print(myCmd)

        for data in myCmd:
            if re.search(r'vpn.conf\b',data): 
                print("Vpn connected")
                self.flag = True
                return self.flag

    def connect_vpn(self,token1):  

        print("#########")
```

x2

```
from x1 import vpn
import json

obj=vpn()

obj.check_vpn()

if(obj.flag == False):
    print("###################   VpN is not connected   ########")
with open('auth1.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    token = data["vpn_detail"]["tokens"]
    for i in range(len(token)):
        token1 = token[i]
        #print(token[i])
        print(token1)
        i = i+1   
        obj.connect_vpn(token1)
```